# How to remove margin-left for new line boxes css

Tags: html, css

I am generating boxes dynamically, I give `margin-left` between boxes when screen overflows it goes to next line but starts with margin-left. How to remove this margin left on next line.

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; float: left;">test</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">test</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">test</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">test</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">test</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">test</div>
```

Issue:

[image]

Here is fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jotftL3z/1/

Comment: How many div you need in a row ??

Comment: it depends on screen size.

Comment: Then use  `margin-right`  instead of     `margin-left`

Comment: Why not setting margin on both sides? So you will never have this issue. So instead `margin-left: 10px;` do `margin-left: 5px;`, `margin-right: 5px`: https://jsfiddle.net/jotftL3z/19/

Comment: "How to remove margin of (generally style) first inline element in line?" still remains an interesting question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can instead give it margin-right :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px;float: left;">test</div>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px; float: left;">test</div>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px; float: left;">test</div>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px; float: left;">test</div>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px; float: left;">test</div>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; margin-right:10px; float: left;">test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove margin-left from all div's and add margin-right. If you want space to left, put all div's inside a div and give margin-left or padding-left.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Add padding to the container, and to the right of each box instead of left (or a margin to the left & right of the boxes, if you don't want the padding in the container).
2. Use the Flexbox Model instead!

Have a look at this, I think you'll find an example for your intended use case: http://flexboxgrid.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will consider using Flexbox Model. thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

You can target the offending margin with nth child CSS.

On desktop this would remove the margin left on every fourth item.

```
div:nth-child(4){
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

You could then adjust the nth child inside media queries for different screen sizes.

Check your CSS here

[CSS tricks Nth child guide](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use margin-right replace form margin left like this

```
[jsfiddle.net/jotftL3z/7][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do one thing just split your margin 10px to 5px and give each side like

```
margin: 0 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to equally space the `<div>` without specific margins you could add a container for all the `div` and add this CSS `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;` on that container. More on the flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). This is also great for making it responsive.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">test</div>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">test</div>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">test</div>
</div>
```

If you must give a `margin-left` and every 6th element comes on its own row then you could also use the [`nth-of-type` CSS psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) on the `div` like this:

```
div:nth-of-type(5n+1) { 
  margin-left: 0; 
}
```

Lastly, as other answers have pointed out, you could also use a `margin-right` instead.